# Converting html to pdf using iText.Html2pdf is taking too long

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

Hi I'm trying to convert a HTML String to pdf using iText.Html2pdf.
It's taking almost 3 minutes to do it.

The code is the following (pretty much a basic example):

```
public byte[] ConvertToPdf(string email)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var properties = new ConverterProperties()
                .SetBaseUri(".")
                .SetCreateAcroForm(false)
                .SetCssApplierFactory(new DefaultCssApplierFactory())
                .SetFontProvider(new DefaultFontProvider())
                .SetMediaDeviceDescription(MediaDeviceDescription.CreateDefault())
                .SetOutlineHandler(new OutlineHandler())
                .SetTagWorkerFactory(new DefaultTagWorkerFactory());

            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(email, memoryStream, properties);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

The file in question generates 6 pages.

Any suggestion?

Comment: It's a single call and I don't think creating the ConverterProperties is taking up 99% of the time (you should check up on that, thoughl) ... so, not much you can do except for run it on a monster of hardware.
Have you tried competitors' solutions for reference?

Comment: hi! Thanks for answering. I was searching for some other solutions, but mostly don't run in .netCore. Do you recommend something?

Comment: Do you have a website or html reference we can test against to verify is any new solutions are faster?